# Ruby send() with validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've the following code in a .html.erb file which is called from show.html.erb.

```
<%-
  platforms = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
%>

<%- platforms.each do |platform| -%>
   <%- if user.send("#{platform}_rate") -%>
   <%= render "users/credentials/#{platform}", user: user %>
<%- else -%>
   Not Connected
<%- end -%>
```

Unfortunately `b_rate` doesn't exist and is breaking with the following error:

```
undefined method `b_rate' for #<User:0x00007hgh9b842ce0>
```

How can I check if each `_rate` exists before using `send` method without getting messy with the code?

Comment: See if it `respond_to?`? It already seems a little messy even before that, though, IMO.

Comment: How do you run this? Please [edit] your question to show an example with output, including any error messages.

Comment: Original question updated.

Comment: `<%- if user.respond_to?("#{platform}_rate") -%>` this works. Thanks @DaveNewton.

Comment: I'd recommend to not use such logic inside view component, I think it would be better to place it in separate method inside user model

Comment: Why do some user instances have those methods and others don't? Are you defining the methods dynamically?

Comment: I would add a method to the `User` model which returns all available rates.

Comment: I would not normally recommend this (too much magic for my liking) but since this is tagged [tag:ruby-on-rails] you could use [`Object#try`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/Object/try) which handles `NoMethodError`. e.g.  `if user.try("#{platform}_rate")`

Answer (score 0):

I went with this, suggested by Dave. Does the job for me. Thanks.

```
  platforms = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
%>

<%- platforms.each do |platform| -%>
   <%- if user.respond_to?("#{platform}_rate") || user.respond_to?("#{platform}_rates") -%>
   <%= render "users/credentials/#{platform}", user: user %>
<%- else -%>
   Not Connected
<%- end -%>
```